# How to solve this exception when playing mp3 in java?

Tags: java, exception, audio, mp3, javasound

I am trying to control mp3 files volume with this code which I've found on internet, but after adding all required jar in library, I am still not able to do so.

Here is what I am using:

```
try {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("Z:\\Best day of my life.mp3"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    gainControl.setValue(-10.0f); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
    clip.start();
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(VolumeTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

With this if I play wav file it works fine but for mp3 I am getting an error such as:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format MPEG1L3 44100.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, stereo, unknown frame size, 38.28125 frames/second,  not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:1304)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1085)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1175)
at com.myPractice.VolumeTest.jButton1ActionPerformed(VolumeTest.java:115)
at com.myPractice.VolumeTest.access$000(VolumeTest.java:23)
at com.myPractice.VolumeTest$1.actionPerformed(VolumeTest.java:54)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And as for mp3 support I already imported mp3spi1.9.5.jar, jl1.0.1.jar and tritonus-share.jar

Comment: Your question(1) is answered in the [JavaSound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info). 1) Both the cause *and* the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to play them you must convert them in the program to a file type that can actually be played such as PCM.

Just refer [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/kashmir/entry/java_sound_api_2_mp3) link

Comment: *"It reads MP3 file, but it has no audio (mixer) line which supports directly MP3 audio format for output. MP3 must be converted to one of the supported audio formats such as PCM."*  This is complete nonsense.  I have a Java based player for MP3 (using the MP3 plugin Jar mentioned in that page) that works just fine for directly playing MP3.

Comment: This is definitely **not** nonsense, but the way to go.
Depending on your SP implementation, an mp3 provider may produce not PCM frames but mp3 packets, which **cannot** be played by the mixer (at least none that I know of). You definitely need to transcode them first as described in the link provide by santhosh.
That said, some SP implementations take a shortcut and convert straight to PCM. If you use one of them you may send data directly to the mixer.